# Show the big clock in tmux after N time of inactivity

Tags: tmux

The big clock can be activated with:

```
t  big clock
```

Is it possible to monitor for inactivity and use it like a screensaver?

Comment: I don't think there is. The clock makes for a crappy screensaver anyways. I use TMUX's lock command to execute cmatrix (much geekier). But if your concerned about security you might want to try http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/tmout-exit-bash-shell-when-no-activity/

Comment: After some 5 minutes of googling I don't think this is available out of the box. It would have to be a custom fork of TMUX solution.

Comment: @sukima this should be the accepted answer

Comment: Thanks @Sukima for cmatrix reference :-) I have filles Feature Request to display clock so we have both cmatrix and clock on a screen saver :-)
https://github.com/abishekvashok/cmatrix

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to display clock on the inactive pane after `monitor-silence` seconds (this focuses on work) and have screensaver / screenlock running after `lock-after-time` seconds (this prevents others to see my screen after inactivity). Use example below to see how it works under 20 seconds (remember to adjust to your needs). Visual bell needs to be disabled as it prevents screensaver.

```
set -g lock-after-time 15
set -g lock-command "cmatrix -abs"
set -g monitor-silence 5
set -g visual-silence off
set -g alert-silence clock
set -g silence-action current
set -g visual-bell off
```

I am using tmux 3.2 on FreeBSD. However this does not seem to be common scenario as sometimes screensaver does not kick in and there is no way to set shell command for `alert-silence` event.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat possible with the introduction of the hook feature in tmux 2.2 & 2.3 ([tmux change log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/master/CHANGES))

You should be able to trigger the clock appearing after a window has been silent for a period of time. Monitoring for user inactivity is still not possible.

You can set the window option `monitor-silence` & use the `alert-silence` hook to start the clock.

See the tmux 2.3 man page about hooks & monitor-silence.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but there is a good alternative not mentioned above which might be of interest to anyone else searching this.

Simply replacing the `lock-command` with a [`tty-clock`](https://github.com/xorg62/tty-clock) invocation works. Its fairly configurable, so setting it as follows would produce something similar to the built in clock.

```
set -g lock-after-time 60
set -g lock-command "tty-clock -Scd 100000000 -C 4"
```

Of course, it has the downside that `tty-clock` needs to be installed - so makes your `.tmux.conf` less portable. Also, it offers no security.